# Keras and Recurrent Neural Networks: What does the input look like for batches of univariate data

Tags: batch-processing, recurrent-neural-network

When training an RNN, often times we specify batches to increase training speed. But what does the input look like for input data? E.g., suppose I have 1000 observations of just temperatures and determine batches of size 100. And let's say we have 4 nodes in a hidden layer.

Is the input simply each temperature? I.e. send temperature 1 through the model, then temperature 2, the temperature 3, etc. until we get to 100, then update weights.

Or are all of the temperatures in the batch positioned as inputs and sent through the model? I.e., we apply the activation function to the whole batch in each node.

I hope this makes sense. Please let me know if you need clarification or more information.

Comment: No, you need to input data in sequence, so each sample fed into the network is already a sequence. Not sure what exactly you are doing, but you should feed in a batch of shape (b, *x) where b is your batch size, and x is the shape of a single sample, where a single sample is the complete timeseries of one sample on which you are attempting to classify.

Comment: So how would that look for the univariate example I have? I take it we would have a (100,1) input? Also, thanks for your reply. I appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Check out this article: https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/